# Unity2D: Don't Destroy On Load UI button

Tags: unity

I have a UI button as a child under my background canvas. What I want to do is to save the button through out scene, I tried using DontDestroy OnLoad but It saved ay canvas and everything under my canvas, rather than saving just the button. Anyway this is my DontDestroyOnLoad script:

```
void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.root.gameObject);
}
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: root returns the top most transform in the hierarchy. So if this script is on the button it will indeed save the entire canvas. Why not try `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);`

Comment: I tried that as well but i got this error: DontDestroyOnLoad only work for root GameObjects or components on root GameObjects.

Comment: I just don't want the UI button to be destroyed when the next scene is loaded. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: From what you tell us, the UI button **already** 'doesn't destroy' on next scene loaded (as you tell us that "It saved (m)y canvas ***and everything under my canvas***"). Also, what your telling us is a statement, not a question. It is important to ensure you ask a question (such as *how can I save my UI button without saving the entire canvas?*), as to ensure we understand what your asking.

Comment: At any rate, I believe your having a problem understanding how Canvas works, and indeed how generic child-parent object relations work, in Unity. As I stated previously, if your button is a child of the canvas (ie. canvas is the *root*), deleting your canvas will *also* delete your button. So unfortunately, in that logic, *you can't have it both ways*.

Comment: Also, any UI elements (including buttons) must have a canvas as an ancestor. Otherwise they can not be displayed. So when you want to retain the button, you also need to retain the canvas it is on.

Comment: I never said that I wanted to delete my canvas, all I said was that I want to save my UI button through out scenes, I tried using DontDestroyOnLoad but all it did was that it saved my canvas and everything under it.

Comment: OK, so if I understood you correctly you have a canvas with lots of stuff on it, including a button. And on scene change you want everything on the canvas to disappear *except* the one button. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I wiped up a script that does this but the solution seem janky. Use it at your own risk.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class TestButtonPersist : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    void Awake()
    {
        //We subscribe to  the event for  loading a scene
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += MyOnLoad;
    }

    void MyOnLoad(Scene scene,LoadSceneMode sceneMode)
    {
        //if our button does not have a parent then we will find it a Canvas.
        if (gameObject.transform.parent == null)
        {
            gameObject.transform.SetParent(
                    GameObject.Find("Canvas").gameObject.transform, false);
            // You might want to use Find with tag here to make sure you will find a canvas
        }
    }

    // This is where the magic happens
    public void LoadLevel()
    {
        // Before we call the code for loading the level, 
        //we make sure to set the button as a root object
        gameObject.transform.SetParent(null,false);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
}
```

The thing is you need to call `transform.SetParent(null,false)` for the object before the scene changes so you will have to do this from your code  that loads a new scene.

Comment: Hi, sorry could I ask you something about your code, you see when I click on the button to activate my frost button it works but when I click on the button again I get this error: (sorry not enough characters)

Comment: Error: MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'FrostScriptButton' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
FrostScriptButton.MyOnLoad (Scene scene, LoadSceneMode sceneMode) (at Assets/Script/FrostScriptButton.cs:34)
UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.Internal_SceneLoaded (Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/SceneManagerBindings.gen.cs:198)

Comment: make a new  question with your new code.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. :). This is the [link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129349/unity2d-dont-destroy-on-load-ui-button-error)