# Unity2D: Don't Destroy On Load UI button Error

Tags: unity

I have two UI buttons, an activation button, and a frost button. The activation button activates my frost button when I click on it , using `OnClick`. I have this script that saves my UI button when a new scene is loaded, however when I click on the activation button to activate my frost button it works a first time, but when I click on the button again (still running the game) I get this error:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'FrostScriptButton' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object. 
>   FrostScriptButton.MyOnLoad (Scene scene, LoadSceneMode sceneMode) (at Assets/Script/FrostScriptButton.cs:34) 
>   UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.Internal_SceneLoade‌​d (Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime‌​/SceneManagerBinding‌​s.gen.cs:198)

And not showing the button anymore. Anyway this is my script:

```
void Awake()
{
    //We subscribe to  the event for  loading a scene
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += MyOnLoad;
}

void MyOnLoad(Scene scene,LoadSceneMode sceneMode)
{
    //if our button does not have a parent then we will find it a Canvas.
    if (gameObject.transform.parent == null)
    {
        gameObject.transform.SetParent(
            GameObject.Find("BackGround Canvas").gameObject.transform, false);
        // You might want to use Find with tag here to make sure you will find a canvas
    }
}


// Use this for initialization

public void Activate ()
{
    frostbutton.SetActive (true);
}

public void LoadLevel()
{
    // Before we call the code for loading the level, 
    //we make sure to set the button as a root object
    gameObject.transform.SetParent(null,false);
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
}
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: Not sure on this but DontDestroyOnLoad might need to be in the Awake() or Start() functions to work correctly.  By the time LoadLevel() is called it may be too late.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it's still showing the same error. Thank you though. :)

Comment: I have my suspicions on the cause, especially given "your script" is actually [another users code to a different question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129340/unity2d-dont-destroy-on-load-ui-button), where they say 'this is dodgey, use it at your own risk'.

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit better? You have two buttons.. do they both have the same script? Is this all thats in the script? Do you mean to say that `OnClick()` triggers `Activate()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your game is not UI intense and have couple of Canvases already with hundreds of UI objects in the scene, you can use this solution.

Keep a Canvas that holds all the buttons you don't want to destroy. Make sure it's screen space is overlaid. Give it the highest `Sort Order` value so it renders over all canvases as well as other overlaid canvases if there are some.

[image]

Now add a script which is assigned to the canvas that holding the buttons you don't want to destroy. Put `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);` at `Awake()` in this script.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your suggestion but now I got two more errors which is the one I mentioned above and: DontDestroyOnLoad only work for root GameObjects or components on root GameObjects. Thank you, for your help, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Separate the canvases that have destroying and non destroying UI objects. Keep the script on the non destroying canvas. You will not need the whole script you used in the question with this solution. Read the solution carefully. There have to be two canvases at least. Script on canvas itself rather than button. There will not be any root issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I did what you said and the don't destroy on load works, however when I click on the activation button again it activates my frost button but when I click on the frost button a second time nothing happen. :(